# Debugging google test usinc CLion; breakpoints do not hit

Tags: c++, cmake, googletest, clion

I recently tried to incorporate google tests to our codebase. I can run tests but I cannot seem to figure out how to debug one!

This is my CMakeLists for a test:

```
add_executable(test_stringUtilities stringUtilitiesTests.cpp)
target_link_libraries(test_stringUtilities PRIVATE gtest_main applicationLibrary)

add_test(
        NAME test_stringUtilities
        COMMAND test_stringUtilities
)
```

And this is a test I am trying to debug (trying to keep it simple; have many more tests):

```
#include <gtest/gtest.h>
#include <string>
#include <StringEncodingUtils.h>



std::string testString{" Test  "};

TEST(stringUtilitiesTests, trimming) {

    EXPECT_EQ(trim(testString), "Test") << "Failed trim";
    EXPECT_EQ(ltrim(testString), "Test  ") << "Failed ltrim";
    EXPECT_EQ(rtrim(testString), " Test") << "Failed rtrim";
}
```

What I am trying to do, is debug a function. Let's say I set a breakpoint in the line

```
    EXPECT_EQ(trim(testString), "Test") << "Failed trim";
```

I would expect this breakpoint to hit but it does not! Instead when I try to run it through the debugger in CLion I get

```
Debugger process finished with exit code 134 (interrupted by signal 6: SIGABRT)
```

I even tried to run it manually through gdb with no luck.

Any thoughts?

EDIT:

I am elaborating on the structure of the tree of the project, since I suspect it matters:

```
├── applicationLibrary
│   ├── CMakeLists.txt
│   ├── src
│   │   ├── CMakeLists.txt
│   │   ├── StringEncodingUtils.cpp
│   │   └── StringEncodingUtils.h
│   └── tests
│       ├── CMakeLists.txt
│       └── hello_test.cc
├── cmake-build-debug
├── CMakeLists.txt
├── googletest
```

Comment: are you sure you setting the correct build type type in cmake? try to add "-DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Debug" to your cmake command for example like this "cmake .. -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Debug"

Comment: @KoronisNeilos Yes, the build type is set to DEBUG for sure :/

Comment: Have you examined the stack when the signal is raised? This might hold a clue as to why your break point isnt being hit - maybe it doesn't even reach that point in your test before SIGABRT is raised?

Comment: Try to set a breakpoint on a line that is not relying on macros, too. It might interfere with the line matching in the debugger.

Comment: I hit and stop on breakpoints but the "Exception breakpoints" don't work. Ie, when something throws, the debugger doesn't stop. It works in a normal executable.